# Cannot access real files when using app_dev.php in Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, css, symfony, assets

I am working with Symfony 2.8 and encounter the problem, that real files within the `web/` dir cannot be found (`HTTP Error 400`) when using the dev controller `app_dev.php`:

```
web/
    css/
        base.css
        base_base_1.css
    images/
        someFile.png
```

I am using a very simply CSS structure. The assets/images are only stored within `web/images` and not copied/linked by `Assetic` or something else. Thus the assets images are simply linked using a "direct" relative URL with the CSS files:

```
// AppBundle/Resources/styles/base.scss
.someClass {
    background: url("../images/someFile.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}

// Page Template
{% stylesheets 
    '@AppBundle/Resources/styles/base.scss'
    filter="scssphp" 
    output="css/base.css" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Depending on whether `app_dev.php` is used or not, this results in using `base.css` or `base_base_1.css`:

```
// app_dev.php NOT uses
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/base.css" type="text/css" />

// app_dev.php used
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app_dev.php/css/base_base_1.css" type="text/css" />
```

No matter if `app_dev.php` is used or not, in both .css files, the path to the image is the same: `url("../images/someFile.png")`

However when calling `example.com/somepage` everything works fine, while calling or `example.com/app_dev.php/somepage` I get an `Error 404`:

```
URL: /app_dev.php/images/someFile.png
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
```

When I test this manually the result is the same: `example.com/app_dev.php/images/someFile.png` leads to an error, while `example.com/images/someFile.png` loads without any problem.

**What am I doing wrong?**

I have created a test file `web/test.php` which shows the same behavior: Calling in normal mode is no problem, calling in `app_dev.php` produces 404. Is this normal behavior of dev-mode?

But why can I access the existing files `base.css` and `base_base_1.css`, no matter wether dev-mode is used or not?

**What can I do, to access the assets in dev-mode?**

Comment: Real assets should not pass the front controller, they are served directly by the webserver. As stated in the answers below, you could/should also use the `asset` function in twig to build paths to assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create css, js and images into the YourBundle/Resources/public/

And then, in version 2.8, you need create the link to web dir with the command.

```
app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

And in the template use:

```
asset('bundles/yourbundlename/css|js|images...')
```

Check http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/templating.html

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this,

http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#linking-to-assets

You can simply use **asset()** twig function to load static assets into view. Giving hard-code path to the asset is highly discouraged.

To link **base.css** into view, it would be something like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="asset('css/base.css')" type="text/css" />
```

**asset()** will always point to your `/web` directory regardless of environment. You can also add [version](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#reference-framework-assets-version) of each asset to make sure assets are up-to-date when using in production.

If you're using `assetic` for `CSS` and `JS`, you can put it on watch during development by following command.

```
php app/console assetic:watch
```

This will help to get the updated code without dumping the `assetic`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have simply replaces `{{ asset_url }}` with `{{ asset('css/base.css') }}`. No both `prod` and `dev` calls link to `base.css`, while `base_base_1.css` is not used anymore. While this solves the problem it has a major downside: Changes to the `CSS` files are not applied automatically any more when reloading the page in `dev` mode. I have to run `assetic:dump` manually or to use `assetic:watch` to see the changes. This is not big deal in general, but it should be possible to work on the `scss` file via FTP an to see the changes without server access to `assetic:dump/watch`